# How to send Verification/Confirmation Email when user have registered in Android?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I've made an UI in xml file and i have Email_Navigator.Java file which can

validate all the fields for Registration but while clicking on Button called

Submit than mail should be gone to the entered Email. how can i do this?

Comment: please show your code and before adding to stack overflow do google atleast

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create classes

1. Session.java

   ```
   private Session createSessionObject() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

       return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
       }
       });
   }
   ```
2. Message.java

   ```
   private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tutorials@tiemenschut.com", "Tiemen Schut"));
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
       message.setSubject(subject);
       message.setText(messageBody);
       return message;
   }
   ```

Define an inner class in the Activity sending the mail like this:

```
private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
    try {
        Transport.send(messages[0]);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Then at last call this method in your onClick:

```
private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody) {
    Session session = createSessionObject();

    try {
        Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session);
        new SendMailTask().execute(message);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** username & password in passswordAuthentication() are your mail credentials which you will be using for sending mails.

For better explaination
Check out this link :
http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-send-e-mail-directly-from-android-application/

Comment: thank you so much...but i am still confused how may i put this code in Android app?